# How to update a Multilist Source dynamically based on Selection made from DropDown Field

Tags: content-editor, custom-field

I have two fields one a Dropdown Field and other a Multilist field. The requirement is, on change of Dropdown field value the Source Tree of Multilist must be updated.
[image]

I tried creating a custom Multilist field and updated the source dynamically. But the source is changing only if I update the dropdown field and save the item. I need the Multilist field to be updated without saving the item after updating the dropdown. Any recommendations will be highly appreciated.

```
public class CustomField : MultilistEx
{
    protected override void DoRender(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        Item current = Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase.GetItem(this.ItemID, Language.Parse(this.ItemLanguage));
        var Dropdownfield = current.Fields["Dropdown"].Value.ToString();
        this.Source = Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase.GetItem(Dropdownfield).Paths.FullPath;
        base.DoRender(output);

    }
}
```

Comment: Sitecore's UI doesn't work like that. You will only be able to read actually saved values from your other fields.